# Does there exists unitary matrix $U$ such that $A=UBU^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given diagonal matrices
$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1^m &   & \\  & \ddots & \\  &   &a_m^m\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=a_1a_2\cdots a_m\begin{bmatrix}\frac{b_1^{m-1}}{b_2\cdots b_m} &   & \\  & \ddots & \\  &   &\frac{b_m^{m-1}}{b_1\cdots b_{m-1}}\end{bmatrix}$, where $a_i\geq 1$ and $b_i\ge 0$.

Question: Does there exists unitary matrix $U$ such that $A=UBU^*$?

We can rewrite them: $\hat{A}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{a_1^{m-1}}{a_2\cdots a_m} &   & \\  & \ddots & \\  &   &\frac{a_m^{m-1}}{a_1\cdots a_{m-1}}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\hat{B}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{b_1^{m-1}}{b_2\cdots b_m} &   & \\  & \ddots & \\  &   &\frac{b_m^{m-1}}{b_1\cdots b_{m-1}}\end{bmatrix}$, 
and further $\tilde{A}=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{a_1} &   & \\  & \ddots & \\  &   &\tilde{a_m}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\tilde{B}=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{b_1}&   & \\  & \ddots & \\  &   &\tilde{b_m}\end{bmatrix}$, where $\tilde{a_i}=\frac{a_1^{m-1}}{a_2\cdots a_m}$, $\tilde{b_i}=\frac{b_1^{m-1}}{b_2\cdots b_m}$.

Then we rewrite the question: Does there exists unitary matrix $U$ such that $\tilde{A}=U\tilde{B}U^*$ if $\mathrm{det}\tilde{A}=\mathrm{det}\tilde{B}=\mathrm{det}I=1$?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial depends only on the conjugaison class, two diagonal matrices are conjugate iff they have the same characteristic polynomial, if so $D_1 = P D_2 P^\top$ with $P$ a permutation matrix

Comment: @reuns, I understood how silly my question was. All the eigenvalues must be equal, so only option is to use permutation matrix. Thanks